# How to make a Skype Out call using asterisks?

Tags: java, asterisk, skype

I've been working on an asterisk-java application and so far I've been able to figure out how to call from one phone to another phone and also one phone to another computer. Now I want it so that I can use my phone to dial a number and if a preceding number is some special character, that number will be dialed through the skype server and call that number using Skype. Of course I will pay for all fees that apply and such.

For example:
If I dial a number such as #1234567888, the # will mean I would want to do a skype out call so the dial string 1234567888 will be called using skype's server.

Is this possible? Any hints or tips would be much appreciated!

Thank you for any help in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

I use ["Skype for Asterisk"](http://www.digium.com/en/products/software/skypeforasterisk.php) by Digium (commercial).

When I want to call some skype user I use his/her id with `Skype/` prefix, so you can replace `#` into this prefix and dial such id.

On Asterisk wiki there is list of Asterisk gateways including free/opensource: [Skype Gateways](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Skype+Gateways), but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Are there any that doesn't cost anything? Thanks again

Comment: I use commercial, but there are free/opensource. Just look for link I added to my response.

Answer (score 0):

Skype for Asterisk will no longer be available after July 26th

I've tried a lot, and finally had luck with freeswitch + skypopen (ex skypiax)

http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_skypopen_Skype_Endpoint_and_Trunk#What_is_Skypopen

( not trivial to implement )